# How can I add params to a post request body?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, download, xls

I have a dynamic array in the view of my rails app and I would like to export it to .xls on button click using the spreadsheet gem.  The button is a link to a download action.  However, the array is long, making the uri too long.

Instead of adding to the querystring of the post request,

```
<a href="<%= controller_action_url(param1: array) %>" data-method="post" remote="true">
  Download
</a>
```

I'd like to add params to the body.  Any way I can do that? So far I've tried the form method...however the `send_data` does not actually send the .xls file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send it as a form. like this.

```
<%= form_tag controller_action_url, remote: true, method: :post do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:params_1, "PARAMS VALUE") %>
  <%= submit_tag("Download") %>
<% end %>
```

This link is always helpful. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#a-generic-search-form

For the AJAX part http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-ajax

Comment: Thank you but I'm having trouble with the `send_data` when I use the form method.  Do you possibly know why the .xls isn't downloading?

Comment: Figured it out! Thank you, @nzajt! To anyone who needs this to work. Remove the `remote: true` from the example above.